# Diffeomorphism group $\text{Diff}_\omega(D^2, \partial D^2)$, exact differential form.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Let $D^2$ denote the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\omega = dx \wedge dy$ denote the standard area form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and on $D^2$ by restriction). Let $\phi$ be a diffeomorphism of $D^2$ which is equal to the identity in a neighborhood of $\partial D^2$, and which preserves area; i.e. $\phi^*\omega = \omega$. We denote the group of such diffeomorphisms by $\text{Diff}_\omega(D^2, \partial D^2)$. I know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683631/does-there-exist-a-1-form-alpha-with-d-alpha-omega) that there is a $1$-form $\alpha$ with $d\alpha = \omega$.

I have two questions.

1. Is $\phi^* \alpha - \alpha$ exact?
2. Is $\phi^*\alpha - \alpha$ equal to $df$ for some smooth function $f$?

Answer (score 3):

$\phi^*\alpha - \alpha$ is closed as 
$$\begin{split}
d (\phi^* \alpha- \alpha) &= d\phi^*\alpha - d\alpha\\
& = \phi^* d\alpha - d\alpha \\
&= \phi^*\omega - \omega  \\
&= \omega - \omega = 0
\end{split}$$

Thus $\phi^*\alpha - \alpha$ is also exact as $D^2$ is contractible, and equals to $df$ for some smooth function $f$.