# What does it mean if divergence of a vector field is zero?

Tags: divergence-operator

I learnt the identity that if $F$ is $C^2$ then div(curl$F$)=$0$. 
Now if I have a vector field $G$, which happens to be that div$G$ = $0$, does this mean that $G$ is the curl of some vector field $F$?
How would I find this if so?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential#Theorem) is a theorem that answers in the affirmative under some conditions.

Answer (score 3):

We can prove that

$E=$curl$(F) \Rightarrow$ div$(E)=0$

simply using the definitions in cartesian coordinates and  the properties of partial derivatives.  But this result is a form of a more general theorem that is formulated in term of [exterior derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) and says that:

> the exterior derivative of an exterior derivative is always null.

In this case $E$ is the exterior derivative of $F$ and div$(E)$ is the exterior derivative of $E$.

Another way to express this general result is to say that $E$ corresponds to an [**exact** differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) just because it is the exterior derivative of a $1-$form corresponding to $F$ and the derivative of an exact form is null.

The question if the inverse is true, i.e. if a form whose exterior derivative is null (we say that it is **closed**) is necessarly exact, is solved by the Poincaré Lemma that says that:

> all closed differential $k-$forms on a **contractable** domain are exact.

This is a very deep result that has to do with the topological fact that  the boundary of a boundary is zero (see [this proof](http://www.oberlin.edu/physics/dstyer/Electrodynamics/DivCurl.pdf) of div$($curl$(F))=0$) and require a definition of contractable space and, more, opens the doors of the de Raham cohomology theory (as you can [see here](http://math.columbia.edu/~dlitt/exposnotes/poincare_lemma.pdf) if you want to know more about the argument).

Your last question about how we can find the vector potential of a field with null divergence, can be reduced to an integration problem as you can [see here](http://galileo.math.siu.edu/mikesullivan/Courses/251/S12/vpot.pdf).

Comment: There’s also a general procedure for finding the antiderivative of a $k$-form (e.g., described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683631/265466)) that is applicable. It doesn’t always find the “nicest” antiderivative, though.