# Problem understanding a solenoidal vector field that is not a curl.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**

In Apostal's calculus volume 2 , there is an example which shows that a solenoidal vector field that is not a curl. Example states that proof is difficult at this stage . Can anyone please me some understanding why this can happen. That is on **what kind of open sets a solenoidal vector field is always a curl of some other vector field in that set?**

NB-Currently a sophomore .

Comment: @hardmath thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you share Apostol's example of the solenoidal vector field that is not a curl? (P.S. Apostol is also misspelled in the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that a solenoidal field is defined as a field whose divergence is null.

The Poincaré Lemma says  that a divergence-free field is the curl of some vector field only if it is defined on a **contractible** set. ( You can see : [What does it mean if divergence of a vector field is zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298757/what-does-it-mean-if-divergence-of-a-vector-field-is-zero/2298976#2298976) )

A classical example is the field:
$$
\bf {V} = \left(\frac{x}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^3},\frac{y}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^3},\frac{z}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)^3} \right)
$$

that is divergence-free but not a curl of any vector field.

Comment: I think there is a slight mistake: the divergence of your $V$ is $2/||(x,y,z)||$. However, $V = (x,y,z)/||(x,y,z)||^3$ does the job.

Comment: Thank you @AlexProvost. I forgot an exponent !  I edit :)