# How to find 1-form for Stokes' Theorem?

Tags: manifolds, vector-analysis, differential-forms

I'm sorry if this is an elementary question, but the book I'm using does not really shed any light on the following issue: for $S$ a compact, oriented 2-surface in $\Bbb R^3$ with boundary $\partial S$ and a smooth 1-form $\omega$ on $S$, we have Stokes' Theorem:
$$ \int_S d\omega = \int_{\partial S} \omega $$
Now, one way we would want to use this theorem is to calculate integrals of the following form:
$$ \int_S \alpha $$
Where $\alpha = \sum_{i,j} f_{i,j} \ dx_i\wedge dx_j$ is a 2-form and again $S$ is our 2-surface with boundary. In this case we would like to say $\alpha = d\omega$ for some 1-form $\omega$, so that we can reduce our integral over $S$ to an integral over $\partial S$. But how do we find this $\omega$? Is there a general procedure? I looked through the book I'm using and it doesn't really talk about this. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683631/265466 for a general method that works on star-shaped domains and (with some modification) on any region diffeomorphic to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2-form $\alpha$ is called *exact* if there exists a 1-form $\omega$ such that $\alpha=d\omega$.  If such an $\alpha$ exists, then $\alpha$ is called a *closed* form (I.e., $d\alpha=0$, since $d\alpha=d(d\omega))=0$.

Every exact form is closed. But [not every closed form is exact](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms)! See an example at the end of this answer. The Poincaré lemma  in that link provides some additional conditions under which a closed form would be exact (and shows you how to compute $\omega$ from $\alpha$, i.e., luck not needed).

So you cannot always find such an $\omega$. However, if you start out with a $\omega$ that you want to integrate over $\partial M$, then you can use Stokes’ theorem to convert it into $\int_{ M} \alpha$.

Example:
This is a fairly standard example. Consider the 1-form $$\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$$ defined on $D=\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$. This form is well-defined and you May recognise it as “$d\theta$”. However, it is not the “d” of any 0-form (there doesn’t exist such a “$\theta$”!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any *straightforward* way to apply Stoke's Theorem without knowin any more information (and in general such a form you are looking for may not exist).

Maybe, since you have a surface in $\mathbb{R^3}$ you could see if this surface is the boundary of a solid in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and if you are lucky $dω$ will be much simpler than $ω$ .