# If curl is $xy \hat{i} + xy \hat{j} + -(x+y)z \hat{k}$ what is the vector function?

Tags: vector-fields

If curl of a vector is $xy \hat{i} + xy \hat{j} + -(x+y)z \hat{k}$ what is the vector ? How to approach the problem.  Is there specific method to get the vector function ? Only thing I get is the usual curl matrix or curl formula. How would I get the the vector by comparing  $(\partial A_z/\partial y - \partial A_x/\partial z) $ = xy $(\partial A_z/\partial x - \partial A_x /\partial z)$ = xy and $(\partial A_y/\partial x - \partial A_x/\partial y )$ = -(x+y)z .

Comment: Have you tried using the usual curl matrix or curl formula? I suspect you should be able to obtain something from the 3 equations

Comment: @CalvinKhor $(\partial A_z/\partial y - \partial A_x/\partial z) $ = xy $(\partial A_z/\partial x - \partial A_x /\partial z)$ = xy and $(\partial A_y/\partial x - \partial A_x/\partial y )$ = -(x+y)z . Would it help me too much?

Comment: I guess not. $$\nabla \times (\nabla \times  u) = \nabla(\nabla\cdot u) - \Delta u$$ may be useful?

Comment: @CalvinKhor please do the problem with the formula you mentioned. It'll help me a lot.

Comment: I don't know if it can be done with it. I'm hoping it leads to an answer.

Comment: @CalvinKhor oh, Sorry I thought you have solved it.

Comment: my initial thought was to assume that $u$ was divergence free, and then compute $ u = (-\Delta)^{-1} \nabla \times (\nabla \times u) $ (i.e. Biot-Savart law) but I'm not sure how to invert the Laplacian on polynomials.

Comment: @CalvinKhor the divergence would be zero  for a curl of a vector.

Comment: yes, but I meant $u$ in my formula, what you are saying would correspond to $\nabla \cdot \nabla\times u = 0$

Comment: @CalvinKhor what is - delta inverse? In your formula?

Comment: Oh, but the curl of a gradient is 0. So if $u = u_1 + \nabla u_2$ then $\nabla \times u = \nabla \times u_1$. The Biot-Savart law, if it applied, would then tell you how to recover $u_1$, and you would get a family of solutions by adding any gradient

Comment: $u = (-\Delta)^{-1}f $ if $u$ solves the equation $-\Delta u = f$

Comment: @CalvinKhor man please write an answer now. I think now you can solve it.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to invert the Laplacian on polynomials. I can't check right now if the green's function solution is well defined, you can check this and if it works you can post an answer :)

Comment: @CalvinKhor anyway thanks for helping.

Comment: Oh, I suspect you can easily compute the solution of the Poisson equation by hand. Do try it and tell me if it works

Comment: Just by trial and error (using the differential form language) I found that $xyz \hat i - xyz \hat j$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to convert to an equivalent differential form and then apply the algorithm described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683675/265466) to find an antiderivative of it. In detail, apply the [Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) to the 1-form $A\,dx+B\,dy+C\,dz$ to get $\eta = A\,dy\wedge dz + B\,dz\wedge dx + C\,dx\wedge dy$. Steps 1 and 2 of the algorithm produce the form $$\left[tzB(tx,ty,tz)-tyC(tx,ty,tz)\right]\,dt\wedge dx + \left[txC(tx,ty,tz)-tzA(tx,ty,tz)\right]\,dt\wedge dy + \left[tyA(tx,ty,tz)-txB(tx,ty,tz)\right]\,dt\wedge dz$$ and so a vector field with curl $(A,B,C)$ is $$\int_0^1 \left[zB(tx,ty,tz)-yC(tx,ty,tz),xC(tx,ty,tz)-zA(tx,ty,tz),yA(tx,ty,tz)-xB(tx,ty,tz)\right]\,t\,dt.$$

In this problem, we have $A:(x,y,z)\mapsto xy$, $B:(x,y,z)\mapsto xy$ and $C:(x,y,z)\mapsto-(x+y)z$, so, after some simplification, $$\mathbf F(x,y,z) = \left[(2x+y)yz\,\mathbf i - (x+2y)xz\,\mathbf j - (x-y)xy\,\mathbf k\right]\int_0^1 t^3\,dt \\ = \frac14\left[(2x+y)yz\,\mathbf i - (x+2y)xz\,\mathbf j - (x-y)xy\,\mathbf k\right].$$

There are, of course, other antiderivatives. Just as you can add an arbitrary constant to the antiderivative of a single-variable scalar function to get another antiderivative, you can add any irrotational vector field to $\mathbf F$ to get another vector field with the same curl.

Comment: As an example of the “constant of integration,” if you compute the difference between this answer and the one obtained by trial and error ($xyz\,\mathbf i - xyz\,\mathbf j$) you’ll find that its curl does indeed vanish.